# Average Logon time by day - python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to identify the average logon by day of week and Standard Deviation by day. I am using python and pandas package for this. Thanks for the assistance.

Data:

```
2016-01-01 13:49:01
2016-01-02 13:49:03
2016-01-03 13:49:04
2016-01-01 13:49:05
2016-01-02 13:49:02
2016-01-03 14:49:01
```

Expected Output:

```
Sun: 13:49:03
Mon: 13:49:02
Tue: 13:49:02

Sun STD: 00:00:01 
Mon STD: 00:00:02
Tue STD: 00:00:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more data and/or an more detailed explanation of what you want. By now, there is too mach space for interpretation.

I understood that you want to see something like the following (copy your data first):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.read_clipboard(header=None)[0])
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.read_clipboard(header=None)[1])

gb = df.B.groupby(df.A.dt.weekday_name)

print(gb.aggregate({'B':max}) - gb.aggregate({'B':min}))
```

This would give you the diff for example.

Otherwise, if you have more data, this would crash. Please have a look on [resampling methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 0):

Id do something like this:

```
import datetime
import statistics
data_org = ['2016-01-01 13:49:01', '2016-01-02 13:49:03', '2016-01-03 13:49:04', '2016-01-01 13:49:05',
        '2016-01-02 13:49:02', '2016-01-03 14:49:01']

data_dict = {}
for entry in data_org:
    day, time = entry.split(' ')

    time = time.split(':')
    time_secs = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(time[0]), minutes=int(time[1]), seconds=int(time[2])).total_seconds()

    if day in data_dict:
        data_dict[day].append(time_secs)
    else:
        data_dict[day] = [time_secs]

stats = {}
for key, times in data_dict.items():
    stats[key] = [statistics.mean(times), statistics.stdev(times)]

print(data_dict)
print(stats)
```

You can then reformat your output and do all the post-prossessing as you like. Have a look at the documentation for detailed info about converting timestamps.